# "filedescriptor out of range in select" error while sending packets using scapy

Tags: python-2.7, scapy

I am facing this issue while sending packets with scapy, and this happening very inconsistently, I just want to know how to debug this issue, is there a way to do a workaround for this.
Can we replace the select.select() call with select.poll(), as I read that select has limit on file descriptors. 
I am not familiar with select or poll, please suggest a better way to debug.

```
File "/root/lib/Packets/UDP_pkts.py", line 177, in send_gre_dns_query
scapy.all.send(subscriber_pkts, count=op_args['pktCount'])
File "/root/thirdparty/lib/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 261, in send
__gen_send(conf.L3socket(*args, **kargs), x, inter=inter, loop=loop, count=count,verbose=verbose, realtime=realtime)
File "/root/thirdparty/lib/scapy/arch/linux.py", line 317, in __init__
_flush_fd(self.ins)
File "/root/thirdparty/lib/scapy/arch/linux.py", line 301, in _flush_fd
r,w,e = select([fd],[],[],0)
ValueError: filedescriptor out of range in select()
```